# Are scipy.signal.correlate and Matlab xcorr the same actions?

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing

I would like to know if scipy.signal.correlate and Matlab xcorr the same actions.

My example in MATLAB

```
Fs_=40175;
t_max=10;
t0_=0:(1/Fs_):t_max;
s0_=chirp(t0_, 400, t_max, 10000)
B_ = xcorr(y,s0_) %y is column from loaded file
t_B = 0:(1/Fs):(1/Fs)*(length(B_)-1)
t_B = t_B - mean(t_B)
plot(t_B, B_)
```

And the same (I think, but not sure) algorithm in Python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import chirp, correlate
Fs_=40175
t_max=10
t0_new=np.arange(0, t_max, 1/Fs_)
s0_new=chirp(t0_new, f0=400, t1=t_max, f1=10000)
B_new = correlate(data['y'], s0_, mode='full')
t_B_new = np.arange(0, (1/Fs)*(B_new.shape[0]), (1/Fs))
t_b_new = t_B_new - np.mean(t_B_new)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.plot(t_b_new[0:B_new.shape[0]], B_new)
plt.xlabel('counts')
plt.ylabel('level')
plt.title('signals')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And absolutely difference plots:
[Python:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r96YL.jpg)
[Matlab:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiR1O.jpg)

Thanks for help

Comment: Are the two input signals the same? I suggest you create an example input signal rather than relying on existing data, so that you (1) know it’s the same, and (2) we can run your code.

Comment: @ Cris Luengo, you are right. I has confused input arrays and as results difference plots... But anyway,  scipy.signal.correlate and Matlab xcorr are the same?

Comment: I don’t know why they would be different,  but I’m not intimately familiar with either. The scipy function seems to be comparable to `convolve` but without flipping the kernel. The MATLAB function computes the cross-correlation function between two signals. I think the purpose is different, but the functionality should be similar enough.